# tinyint in sql server tables converted to byte in edmx

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am working on asp.net application and I have generated entity model (edmx) from database. I see that all the fields which were tinyint in database are converted to byte. When I try to fix the model using property windows and changing the type, I start getting Model validation errors.

Please tell me how to fix it

Comment: tinyint is equivalent to byte (0..255); what do you want to fix/change ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **tinyInt** will become a **byte**, a **smallInt** will become **int16**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344.aspx